# Linker option for multi-project solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, project, solution

Good day to you all. There's one question I'd like to ask you.

Actually, I quite acquainted with setting linker project for single-project solution, so the possibility of me looking at the wrong place is practically non-existent.

So, the point is - when I try to change properties for one of the solution's projects, linker option is missing, while it's present when I do the same thing for single-project solution

[Multi-project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0aKc.png)

[Single-project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1m3Z.png)

So, the thing I wanted to ask is if there's any way to change linker options? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the images I see two projects. One of them is a project for a library that logically doesn't have a linker option.

Comment: Ok... Thanks for pointing that out. I'm officially idiot now(