# Apply a property change to all DLL projects in a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a solution containing approximately 150 projects, including static libraries, dynamic libraries and executables as well as a few Makefile based projects for good measure, so I have an extended version of [this guy's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12339672/613064).

I need to apply a change to the linker page of all EXE and DLL projects (add `/FIXED:NO` for the benefit of Rational Purify). Is there a way I can do this easily, e.g. with the help of a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the project files directly - they are XML after all, and you can easily discover what change needs to be done in them to add the flag. Then you can write an e.g. Python script to modify all project files.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a common project property, Then you can modify the related projects to inherit this common property, so when next time you just need to modify the common project property, then the projects inherit it will automatically sync the new settings. [Property Sheets (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

To apply project settings that are defined in property sheets using the Inherited Project Property Sheets property:

1. To apply project settings that are defined in property sheets using the Inherited Project Property Sheets property
2. Open your project in the Visual Studio IDE.
3. In Solution Explorer, right-click the node for the project or the property sheet that will inherit the project configuration.
4. On the shortcut menu, click Properties. The property pages for your project will appear.
   Use the Configuration control to specify which project configuration to apply the project settings.
5. In the Inherited Project Property Sheets field of the General property page, enter the path to the property sheet that contains the settings you want to inherit.
6. Click Apply.

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly the sort of thing property sheets were designed for. Create a hierarchy of property sheets which contain settings that are common to certain types of project, then attach them to the relevant projects, using property manager (View menu -> Property manager).

For example:

> - All.props -> settings common to all projects
> - Debug.props -> settings common only to debug builds
> - Release.props -> settings common only to release builds
> - Static.props -> settings common only to static library projects
> - Dynamic.props -> settings common only to dynamic library projects
> - Executable.props -> settings common only to executable projects

This will require a small amount of work up-front, to add the property sheets to your existing projects. Then, whenever you create a new project, all you have to do is attach the relevant property sheets. Maintenance becomes easy - to change a setting and have that change apply to all executable projects, you simply update the property sheet `Executable.props`.

Note: property sheets are sorted according to their place in the hierarchy, so that a setting which is in a property sheet higher up will override the same setting in a sheet which is lower down the list. This is a big advantage - you can place your default settings in `All.props` (from my example above), and then override settings in more specific property sheets. If you have a one-off project with its own unique settings, then modifying the project settings directly will override all property sheets.